# How to push user to instagram share page?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app where I want to push user to instagram app without specifying any text content nor images for them. I just need them to type on the sharing page. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a third-party module for this `react-native-send-intent` to share via phone.

for this I write a helper function using this module:

```
import SendIntentAndroid from 'react-native-send-intent';

export function shareIntent({subject, title, body}) {
  return SendIntentAndroid.openChooserWithOptions(
    {
      subject: subject,
      text: body,
    },
    title,
  );
}
```